# mousedown and mouseup dragging function touch screen?

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function to move background when user click in the image.

My problem is, I need it to work on touch screen too. any ideas?

```
var isDragging = "false";
$("#back").mousedown(function() {
    isDragging = "true";
})
$("#back").mouseup(function() {
    isDragging = "false";
});
```

when user click in `back` div this function will return true if he keeps mousedown, then when he moves the mouse I change the background position. How to make it work in touch too?

my full script:

https://jsfiddle.net/mnu2da0L/

Comment: You can try `$("#back").on('mouseenter touchstart, function....`

Comment: I also think you need to use `mousemove` so you image will follow your image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you want;

```js
var isDragging = "false";

function dragImage(e){
    if(isDragging == "true"){

        var mY=0;

        var x = e.pageX;
        var y = e.pageY;

        $('#back').css('background-position', x + 'px ' + y + 'px');
    }
    $("#drag").text(isDragging);
}
$("#back").on('mouseenter touchstart mousemove', function(e){
    isDragging = "true";
    dragImage(e)
})
$("#back").on('mouseleave touchend', function(e){
    isDragging = "false";
    dragImage(e)
})
$("#back").click(function(e){

    // function to check dragging
    $("#back").mousedown(function() {
        isDragging = "true";
    })
    $("#back").mouseup(function() {
        isDragging = "false";
    })

    document.getElementById("back").style.cursor = "all-scroll";

    //change position
    $('#back').mousemove(function(e){
        dragImage(e)
    });    
});
```

```css
#back{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fc/Gumbo_Limbo_Tree_DeSoto_National_Monument.JPG);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="back"></div>

<span id=drag>click in the image above to drag</span>
```